# What is the $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

What is the limit of
$\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4}$?

I attempted the problem via L^Hopital's Rule so I rewrote it as

$$y=\frac{\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4}$$

then took the natural of both sides

$$\ln(y)=\ln(\frac{\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4})$$

then using the properties of logarithms I came to the conclusion that

$$\ln(y)= \ln(\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2})+\ln(x^4)$$
$$\ln(y)= \ln(\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2})+4\cdot \ln(x)$$

So then I took the limit as the $\ln(y)$ approaches 0.

$$\lim_\limits {x \to 0} (\ln(\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2})+4\cdot \ln(x))$$

Here I used L'Hopital's Rule and got

$$\lim_\limits {x \to 0} \frac{-\sin(x)+x}{\cos(x)-1+x^2}+\frac{4}{x}$$

then got a common denominator

$$\lim_\limits {x \to 0} \frac{-\sin(x)+x+4 \cdot (\cos(x)-1+x^2)}{x\cdot (\cos(x)-1+x^2)}$$

I clearly made a mistake somewhere because the denominator is 0.  **The answer by the way is $\frac{1}{24}$.** I have no idea how to arrive at that conclusion.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{\cos x - 1 + \frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4}}$? The limit as written currently is infinite.

Comment: You surely mean $\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}$; the limit should be $1/4!$

Comment: @JoeyZou Yes you are right I made a mistake posting the problem.

Comment: The $\ln$ trick is a way to make L'Hopital's rule work in unusual situations, like $x^x$ - it's not part of L'Hopital. In a situation like this, where you have a fraction and no variable exponents, just plain old L'Hopital is the way to go.

Comment: @Reese Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem should read $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x) - 1 + \tfrac {x^2}2}{x^4};$$ i.e., the sign of the $1$ should be flipped. Otherwise the top goes to $2$ and the bottom to $0$ so the limit is $+\infty$. As I have written it, you can simply use l'Hopital's rule several times: \begin{align*}\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x) - 1 + \tfrac {x^2}2}{x^4} &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\sin(x) +x }{4x^3} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\cos(x) + 1}{12x^2} \\ 
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{24x}\\ &= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x)}{24} = \frac 1 {24}.\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks I made a mistake in the posting the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Using Taylor series $$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{720}+O\left(x^8\right)$$ So $$\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{720}+O\left(x^8\right)$$ $$\frac{\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4}=\frac{1}{24}-\frac{x^2}{720}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another take with minimum number of applications of L'Hospital's Rule. We have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\cos x - 1 + \dfrac{x^{2}}{2}}{x^{4}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{\cos 2t - 1 + 2t^{2}}{16t^{4}}\text{ (putting }x = 2t)\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{16}\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{2t^{2} - 2\sin^{2}t}{t^{4}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{8}\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{t^{2} - \sin^{2}t}{t^{4}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{8}\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{t - \sin t}{t^{3}}\cdot\frac{t + \sin t}{t}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{8}\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{t - \sin t}{t^{3}}\cdot\left(1 + \frac{\sin t}{t}\right)\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{t - \sin t}{t^{3}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{1 - \cos t}{3t^{2}}\text{ (via L'Hospital's Rule)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{12}\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{1 - \cos^{2} t}{t^{2}(1 + \cos t)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{24}\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{\sin^{2} t}{t^{2}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{24}\notag
\end{align}
If you have studied Taylor series expansions then that is the best technique to solve such problems (see the answer by Claude Leibovici for details).